how to restore objectbox-model.json file after building
I'm using flutter with windows desktop and forget submit objectbox-model.json file to git. The App already run in the production envionment, how to restore the objectbox-model.json file working with production database, and can help me to persitent to VCS.
how to find the objectbox-model.json file on prodcution env

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


how to find the objectbox-model.json file on prodcution env

You can't, your best option is to rebuild it by hand:

Make sure that the generated objectbox.g.dart file is the version released (commit it).
Re-run the code generator with dart run build_runner build. This will create a new objectbox-model.json, but also overwrite the Dart file.
Revert changes to objectbox.g.dart.
In the Dart file, look for getObjectBoxModel(). It's a code representation of the model JSON file.
Copy the IDs and UIDs to the JSON file and make sure all other info matches (like names, properties, flags). Note that in the JSON ID and UID are combined into "ID:UID" format.

It can help (after committing changes to the JSON file!) to re-run the generator, then to look in the generated Dart file for any missed changes.
